# How can i make JavaScript If Style Color work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple if condition that checks the color of a element...

```
function changeBackgroundColor(element) {
          if (element.target.style.color == "#1abc9c"){
            // Do nothing
          } 
          else { // Whatever }
```

But it is not working.
If i use common names like "Yellow, green, etc" it works.
Any tips?

Comment: You need a RGB-object for the check. Instead of #<hex> you need rgb(red, green, blue) (0-255)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

style.color gives the direct color name or rgb value. It does not gives hex code. So for your case, you first need to change your hex code to rgb, then compare it with style.color
So what you can do you can create a utility function

```js
function getRgbFromHex(hexColorCode){
  const hexCode =  hexColorCode.startsWith('#') ? hexColorCode.substr(1) : hexColorCode;
  const hexR = hexCode.substring(0,2);
  const hexG = hexCode.substring(2,4);
  const hexB = hexCode.substring(4,6);
  
  return `rgb(${parseInt(hexR, 16)},${parseInt(hexG, 16)},${parseInt(hexB, 16)})`
  }
```

and then you can change your if condition to
**UPDATE** Removing spaces from style.color

```
if (element.target.style.color.replace(/\s/g,'') == getRgbFromHex("#1abc9c"))
```

Comment: Hello, i tested your function but didnt work. I used console.log to check if it returned the RGB, the conversion was a success but for some reason it is not working... I even tried storing the value on a variable and changed the if condition to: if (element.target.style.color == rgbConvertedColor) but nothing :|

Comment: `element.target.style.color` is `rgb(26, 188, 156)`  (on Chrome) and `getRgbFromHex` returns `rgb(26,188,156)`, those don't match due to the spaces.

Comment: @RaulChiarella Updated my answer to remove spaces.